# Why is Androids SpeechRecognizer automatically stopping itself

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

### Issue number 1:

The following settings are being completely ignored

```
        putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS,
            (5000).toLong()
        )
        putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,
            (5000).toLong()
        )
        putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,
            (5000).toLong()
        )
```

I'm not sure what else to say other than these settings do absolutely nothing, regardless of how I set up my logic (see below for my current implementation).

### Issue number 2:

`onBeginningOfSpeech()` is called when no speaking has taken place. Which then causes recognition to stop prematurely (within 800-1500ms) since it will subsequently call `onEndOfSpeech()` and `onError()` where the error is `ERROR_NO_MATCH`
There are some caveats to this;
Firstly, this occurs only when the phone HAS an internet connection. In other words, if you were to have downloaded the language packs for offline use and then forced the phone into airplane mode, this issue would not occur. Secondly, in the case where the phone DOES have internet connection, `onBeginningOfSpeech()` seems to be called when any tiny sound in the background occurs. I.e. In dead silence it will not be called, but if you lightly tap a nearby surface with your finger it will trigger and then cause the issue. "It could hear a pin drop" as they say.
P.s. This combined with `Issue number 1 (see above)` make the `SpeechRecognizer` incredibly difficult to use.

### Testing for the issues above

**All issues above have been verified to be happening on a fully functional, non-rooted, pixel 4a device running Android 11.**

### The following is my implementation of speech recognition:

```
object SpeechRecognitionUtil {
    const val logTag = "SpeechRecognitionUtil"

    val speechRecognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH).apply {
        putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
        )
        putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true)
        putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "es-US")
        putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 20)
        putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS,
            (5000).toLong()
        )
        putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,
            (5000).toLong()
        )
        putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,
            (5000).toLong()
        )
    }

    fun setupSpeechRecognizer(
        context: Context,
        onError: (Int) -> Unit = {},
        onReadyForSpeech: (Bundle) -> Unit = {},
        onEndOfSpeech: () -> Unit = {},
        onResults: (Bundle) -> Unit = {},
        onEvent: (Bundle) -> Unit = {},
        onPartialResults: (Bundle) -> Unit = {},
        onBufferReceived_: (ByteArray) -> Unit = {},
        onEvent_: (Int, Bundle) -> Unit = { _, _ -> }
    ): SpeechRecognizer? {
        return when {
            SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(context) -> {
                val speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context)
                speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(SimpleRecognitionListener(
                    onError_ = { code: Int ->
                        onError(code)
                    },
                    onBufferReceived_ = {
                        onBufferReceived_(it)
                    },
                    onReadyForSpeech_ = {
                        onReadyForSpeech(it)
                    },
                    onBeginningOfSpeech_ = {
                    },
                    onEvent_ = { integer: Int, bundle: Bundle ->
                        onEvent_(integer, bundle)
                    },
                    onEndOfSpeech_ = {
                        onEndOfSpeech()
                    },
                    onPartialResults_ = {
                        onPartialResults(it)
                    },
                    onResults_ = {
                        onResults(it)
                    }
                ))

                speechRecognizer
            }
            else -> {
                Log.i("SpeechRecognizer", "Recognition is NOT available!")
                null
            }
        }
    }
}

fun Bundle.recognizedWords() = getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)
fun Bundle.confidenceScores() = getFloatArray(SpeechRecognizer.CONFIDENCE_SCORES)

class SimpleRecognitionListener(
    val onReadyForSpeech_: (Bundle) -> Unit = {},
    val onBeginningOfSpeech_: () -> Unit = {},
    val onRmsChanged_: (Float) -> Unit = {},
    val onBufferReceived_: (ByteArray) -> Unit = {},
    val onEndOfSpeech_: () -> Unit = {},
    val onError_: (Int) -> Unit = {},
    val onResults_: (Bundle) -> Unit = {},
    val onPartialResults_: (Bundle) -> Unit = {},
    val onEvent_: (Int, Bundle) -> Unit = { _, _ -> }
) : RecognitionListener {
    private var performingSpeechSetup = true

    override fun onReadyForSpeech(bundle: Bundle) {
        Log.d(SpeechRecognitionUtil.logTag, "onReadyForSpeech()::Bundle=$bundle")
        performingSpeechSetup = false
        onReadyForSpeech_(bundle)
    }

    override fun onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(SpeechRecognitionUtil.logTag, "onBeginningOfSpeech()")
        onBeginningOfSpeech_()
    }

    override fun onRmsChanged(rms: Float) {
//        Log.i(logTag, "onRmsChanged()::Rms=$rms")
        onRmsChanged_(rms)
    }

    override fun onBufferReceived(byteArray: ByteArray) {
        Log.d(
            SpeechRecognitionUtil.logTag,
            "onBufferReceived()::byteArray=$byteArray, \nwords="
        )
        onBufferReceived_(byteArray)
    }

    override fun onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(SpeechRecognitionUtil.logTag, "onEndOfSpeech()")
        onEndOfSpeech_()
    }

    override fun onError(code: Int) {
        Log.d(SpeechRecognitionUtil.logTag, "onError()::code=$code")
        if (performingSpeechSetup && code == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH) return
        else {
            onError_(code)
        }
    }

    override fun onResults(bundle: Bundle) {
        Log.d(
            SpeechRecognitionUtil.logTag,
            "onResults()::Bundle=$bundle, \n" +
                    "Recognized words=${bundle.recognizedWords()}\n" +
                    "Confidence scores=${bundle.confidenceScores()}"
        )
        onResults_(bundle)
    }

    override fun onPartialResults(bundle: Bundle) {
        Log.d(
            SpeechRecognitionUtil.logTag, "onPartialResults()::Bundle=$bundle, \n" +
                    "Recognized words=${bundle.recognizedWords()}"
        )
        onPartialResults_(bundle)
    }

    override fun onEvent(event: Int, bundle: Bundle) {
        Log.d(SpeechRecognitionUtil.logTag, "onEvent()::event=$event, \nbundle=$bundle")
        onEvent_(event, bundle)
    }
}
```

```
class MainVM(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    enum class RecordingState {
        IDLE, RECORDING;
    }


    private var speechRecognizer: SpeechRecognizer? = null
    private val _recording = MutableLiveData(RecordingState.IDLE)
    val recordingState: LiveData<RecordingState> = _recording

    private fun initSpeechRecoginizer() {
        // Destroy old recognizer
        speechRecognizer?.cancel()
        speechRecognizer?.destroy()
        speechRecognizer = null

        // Create new recognizer
        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognitionUtil.setupSpeechRecognizer(getApplication(),
            onPartialResults = { _ -> },
            onEndOfSpeech = {
                _recording.value = RecordingState.IDLE
            },
            onResults = {},
            onError = {})
    }

    fun startRecording() {
        initSpeechRecoginizer()
        speechRecognizer?.let {
            it.startListening(SpeechRecognitionUtil.speechRecognizerIntent)
            _recording.value = RecordingState.RECORDING
        }
    }

    fun stopRecording() {
        speechRecognizer?.stopListening()
        _recording.value = RecordingState.IDLE
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        speechRecognizer?.destroy()
        speechRecognizer = null
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val logTag = "MainActivity"

    @ExperimentalAnimationApi
    @ExperimentalPagerApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                ScreenMain()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ScreenMain() {
        val vm = getViewModel<MainVM>()
        val recordingState by vm.recordingState.observeAsState(RecordingState.IDLE)

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(20.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
        ) {
            Button(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                .height(50.dp),
                onClick = {
                    when (recordingState) {
                        RecordingState.IDLE -> {
                            vm.startRecording()
                        }
                        RecordingState.RECORDING -> {
                            vm.stopRecording()
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                val textString = when (recordingState) {
                    RecordingState.RECORDING -> {
                        "Stop Recording"
                    }
                    RecordingState.IDLE -> {
                        "Start Recording"
                    }
                }
                Text(textString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="some.example.app">

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="EXAMPLE"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I left an issue with Google on their issue tracker (here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197284982) , if you have had any trouble with SpeechRecognizer in the past I urge you to upvote/star it and even leave a comment if you could. Thank you.

Comment: This should be closed because it's just a bug report (reported elsewhere), and not about Android, but a specific Google closed source app?, which implements the SpeechRecognizer API. Also, it covers 2 unrelated issues. There are other SpeechRecognizer implementations, e.g. https://github.com/ccoreilly/LocalSTT, https://github.com/Kaljurand/K6nele-service, etc.,  which might or might not behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

As for the first issue, it is even mentioned [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent#EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS) for each of the three  constants:

> Note that it is extremely rare you'd want to specify this value in an
> intent. If you don't have a very good reason to change these, you
> should leave them as they are. Note also that certain values may cause
> undesired or unexpected results - use judiciously! Additionally,
> depending on the recognizer implementation, these values may have no
> effect.

The second issue is indeed annoying. Good spot there about the internet connection, I have never noticed this (although it can be OS version and/or device specific). I doubt there is a way around this other than processing all events and reenable the recognizer on erroneous ones.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the documentation. 
"Depending on the recognizer implementation" However ANY implementation seems to be non functional. My setup above for example is a very basic set up - Which scenarios does it work then?

Comment: @TomTaila I don't think they are talking about the listener, rather about the system recognizer. In my view it means that it _may_ work on _some_ devices. In that case it simply cannot be relied upon for basic functionality.